# Why is it enough to get a holomorphic extension in a neighbourhood of a point?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

> Let $D \subseteq \mathbb C^n$ be a domain and $E \subseteq D$ be a set such that given $p \in D$ there exists a ball $B(p, \varepsilon)$ and a non-constant holomorphic function $f$ on $B(p, \varepsilon)$ such that $f\ \rvert_{E\ \cap\ B(p,\varepsilon)} = 0.$ Let $h$ be a holomorphic function on $D \setminus E.$ Let $h$ be locally bounded on $D$ (i.e. given any $\Omega \subseteq \subseteq D$ the function $h$ is locally bounded on $\Omega \setminus E).$ Then $h$ has a holomorphic extension to $D.$

It is clear that $E$ is nowhere dense because if $E$ has the above property then so has $\overline E$ and if $a$ is an interior point of $\overline E$ then the given condition would imply that there exists a open neighbourhood $U$ of $a$ and a non-constant function $f$ holomorphic around $a$ such that $f$ is identically zero on an open neighbourhood $V \subseteq U$ of $a.$ But then identity theorem would imply that $f \equiv 0,$ which is a contradiction to the assumption that $f$ is non-constant. So if such an extension exists it is uniquely determined by $h.$

The lecture notes I am following claimed that it is enough to get an extension to a neighbourhood of a point. But how does this imply the general result I would like to show? Could anyone please shed some light on it?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If $D=\mathbb C$ and $E=\{0\}$, then $f(z)=z$ and any ball $B(p,\epsilon)$ satisfy the condition, but $h(z)=1/z$ cannot be extended?

Comment: @EricLey$:$ $h$ is also taken to be locally bounded on $D$ which I forgot to mention.

Comment: $E$ is an analytic submanifold of $D$. If $h$ is bounded near $E$ then this is just Riemann's second extension theorem. But If $h$ is not required to be locally  bounded, consider $E=\mathbb C\times 0$ and $f(z_1,z_2)=(0,z_2)$ and $h(z_1,z_2)=1/z_2$ then $h$ still cannot be extended?

Comment: @EricLey$:$ But modulo those hypothesis as in the modified statement why does it suffice to show the existence of a holomorphic extension in a neighbourhood of a point? Is there any way to paste those neighbourhoods in a convenient way so that those pieces put together nicely to produce a holomorphic function on $D.$ This is the only place I am struggling with. Do we have something like holomorphic partitions of unity? Haven't heard about those things though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theorem is [Riemann's Second Extension Theorem](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Extension_theorems_(in_analytic_geometry))

Although we do not have "holomorphic partitions of unity", we do have identity theorem which allows us to glue things together. If $U$ and $V$ are two connected neighborhoods and $h$ can be extended in $U$ and in $V$, and if they intersects non-trivially, then we have a neighborhood $W\subset (U\cap V)\setminus E$ where $h$ has already been defined, so two extensions of $h$ must coincides on $U\cap V$ by identity theorem. As a consequence, when we have already extended $h$ to $h_j$ in a cover $\{U_j\}$ of $D$, simply let $h|_{U_j}=h_j$ would give us a well-defined function on $D$.

Thus it suffices to prove the whole thing near arbitrary $p\in E$. The rest of the proof can be found in standard textbooks ( for example, Shabat's "Introduction to Complex Analysis")

Comment: How do you know that $(U \cap V) \setminus E$ is open in $U \cup V\ $?

Comment: You are right, $(U\cap V)\setminus E$ might not open, but we can always find a neighborhood $W\subset (U\cap V)\setminus E$. Note that for a defining neighborhood $B=B(p,\epsilon)$ of $E$, we can shrink $B$ so that it lies in $U\cap V$, then $E\cap B$ is closed in $B$, and thus we can choose $W\subset B\setminus E$

Comment: You have proved that $E$ is nowhere dense so simply let $W=(U\cap V)\setminus \bar E$

Comment: $:$ This is really nice observation. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: So it is enough to show the extension on a neighbourhood of $0.$ Right? Hence by the definition of $E$ we may assume that $E \subseteq \{z \in \mathbb C\ |\ f(z) = 0\}$ for some holomorphic function $f$ defined on a neighbourhood of zero. But the lecture notes I am using assumes that $E$ is the zero set of some holomorphic function defined on a neighbourhood of $0.$ Why does it suffice to assume?

Comment: The lecture notes is based solely on R. Michael Range's book. Theorem $3.4$ of this book also made these considerations.

Comment: The way I have finally been almost able to overcome this is the following. Suppose we proved the result $H = Z : = \{z \in \mathbb C\ |\ f(z) = 0\}.$ Now if $H \subseteq Z$ we note that any holomorphic function $h$ defined on a neighbourhood of $P^n(0, \delta) \setminus E$ is automatically holomorphic on $P^n(0,\delta) \setminus Z,$ as the latter is contained in the former. Now using the first part we can extend it to a holomorphic function defined on the whole of $P^n(0,\delta).$ So the only thing we need to ensure is whether $H\ \rvert_{P^n(0,\delta) \setminus E} = h.$ contd...

Comment: Let $H\ \rvert_{P^n(0,\delta)} = \overline h.$ But then we have $\overline {h}\ \rvert_{P^n(0,\delta) \setminus Z}=h\ \rvert_{P^n(0,\delta) \setminus Z}.$ Now since $f$ is non-constant it follows that $P^n(0,\delta)\setminus Z$ is a non-empty open subset of $P^n(0,\delta) \setminus E.$ But does it imply that $h = \overline {h}$ on $P^n(0, \delta) \setminus E.$ The problem is that $P^n(0,\delta) \setminus E$ is not necessarily a domain i.e. in particular connected. When we say a function $f$ is holomorphic on a set $A$ do we always mean it to be holomorphic on an open and connected set contd...

Comment: containing the set $A.$ This is the only part I am supposed to know. Let $A \subseteq \mathbb C^n$ and $U \supseteq A$ be an open set containing $A.$ Then does there exist an open set $V \subseteq U$ containing $A$ such that $V$ is connected. I don't think it is true when $A$ is not connected.

Comment: Sorry I meseed with $H$ and $E.$ In my first comment the first two $H$'s should be read $E.$  Also in the second comment the first sentence should be $H\ \rvert_{P^n(0,\delta) \setminus E} = \overline {h}.$ Sorry for the unavoidable typos.

Comment: Got it. If a set is not connected we can restrict ourselves to its connected components and that does the job.

Comment: @Anacardium: I think to assume E is the zero set is trivial, we only need to prove the result in $B(p,\epsilon)$, where $E$ is exactly the zero set.

Comment: Exactly that's what I actually did. But if we assume that $E$ is the zero set of a holomorphic function around a point say $0$ then does it imply that $E$ has the required property i.e. $E$ Is locally a zero set of some holomorphic function.